# Drawing text at a CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I created a UIView with a custom triangle using UIBezierPath and draw(_ rect: CGRect).

I want to add text labels to the triangle for each of its three points at their CGpoints.

How do I do that?

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        color.set()
        pathForTriangle().stroke()
    }
}
```

---

Solution based on some of Mathias Quintero's answer and some of Sulthan's advice (Label updates when triangle points update):

```
func addUILabels() {
    calculatePoints()
    let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: point1, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 20)))
    addSubview(label1)
    label1.text = "test"
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
{
    color.set()
    pathForTriangle().stroke()
    let subViews = self.subviews
    for subview in subViews{
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    addUILabels()
}
```

Comment: You already indicated that you are working in Swift. No need to add it to the title.

Comment: Adding views in `layoutSubviews` is not a good idea.

Comment: @Sulthan please could you elaborate on the downside, and suggest an alternative?

Comment: @JennyMakula `layoutSubviews` can be called multiple times. Calling `addSubview` will actually make `layoutSubviews` to be called again. Therefore there is a high probability you will add multiple labels by mistake. Changing frames (positions) in `layoutSubviews` is good, adding new views not that good.

Comment: @Sultan thanks, I see, I got to create the label first and then use layoutSubviews() to move it. What do I use to change frame position? and how do I make sure it updates when the points of the triangle updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding TextLabels should not happen as part of the drawing inside of the view. Instead what you should do is add the labels as subviews of your view.

addSubview(:) should do the trick.

When it comes to placing the labels correctly you'll have to think of either adding some constraints or manually changing the frame of the labels to be at the correct position.

You can and should do all of this in viewWillLayoutSubviews() or layoutSubviews() in Swift3

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how I should implement this code? Does this code on into TriangleView or the ViewController? Also, do I end up having to reference the coordinate system of the superview or can I use the same coordinate system as the triangle drawing.

Comment: you would be implementing this in the layoutSubviews() method of your TriangleView. You need to create your label. Just let label = UILabel(). Add it to your view: so addSubview(label)

Comment: Also, how do I make sure it updates when the GGPoints of the triangle is updated by the model?